# Is there a java version of EGLImage to read pixel from OpenGL efficiently?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I'm working on video editing APP with the use of OpenGL. In Android version 4.2 or lower, I can apply shader codes on video frames in OpenGL, but I get a bottleneck on copying the video frames back to memory for video encoding, since surface input for video encoder is not available until Android 4.3.

The traditional glReadPixels() gives unacceptable performance, and I'm trying to find alternatives. EGLImage([Reference 1](https://vec.io/posts/faster-alternatives-to-glreadpixels-and-glteximage2d-in-opengl-es), [Reference 2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opengl-es-to-accelerate-apps-with-legacy-2d-guis)) seems to be a good candidate, since it does not requires OpenGL ES 3.0. However, the related classes EGLImageKHR and the wrapper GraphicBuffer are written in C++, so it cannot be directly used in my APP, which use java to control the camera input and video decoder.

Is there a same usage of EGLImageKHR or similar alternatives that can be used in java, or more precisely, incorporated with the Android MediaCodec architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Java wrapper for those EGL classes.  The Java wrappers are just that -- simple procedurally-generated wrappers -- so you can write your own if you want to get into JNI.  (Sounds like you were hoping to avoid that though.)  I don't think any of the PBO stuff is wrapped either.

GraphicBuffer is not part of the public API, so using it from app code is not recommended.

There really isn't a fast + easy way to do this pre-4.3.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. The main problem is that I use pure java code to put the frames onto openGL surface (either decoded or captured by camera). I'm finding a way to use the EGL classes in C code (by JNI if needed) after the frame is "ready", otherwise I have to change the video-processing codes to C (This is what I really want to avoid.)